# Dot Net Core - How to Prevent appsettings.production.json from changing upon publish

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

I'm publishing my .net core website to the server. Here is the code that adds Json files to my content path:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(contentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true);
```

and here is how the related part of the solution looks:

[image]

In my production computer, I have a `appsettings.production.json` file. I recently had to manualy add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to my connection string.

But everytime I publish the app, that file is reverted to the previous production configuration.

I don't know where the contents of that file is stored and how it remembers its previous state.

Comment: Do you mean you want to publish appsettings.production.json when publish the project.If so,I tried `var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

            // custom config file
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Production.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
            .Build();` in program.cs main method,and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to prevent any changes to appsettings.production.json on publish.

Comment: Yes,it will not change the content of appsettings.production.json.The code is help you to publish appsettings.production.json to publish folder when you publish the project.So if you don't want to publish appsettings.production.json as it in the project,what do you want?

Comment: You're saying if I remove .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Production.json") it will fix the problem?

Comment: No,the code i said is added to  Program.cs.If you use `$"appsettings.{environmentName}.json"`,you need to make "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" in lauchsettings.json is `production`.So that you can publish `appsettings.production.json`.